# A fonte não altera ela só muda o weight mas não o family no front-end!

Tags: wordpress, css3, wordpress-theme, css-font-face

A fonte não altera o family só o width no front e não mostra erro algum no console!

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");
.menu-vin li a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list-inline menu-vin">
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/">INICIO</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/quemsomos">QUEM SOMOS?</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/celulas">CÉLULAS</a></li>
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/contato">CONTATO</a></li>
</ul>
```

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu");
.menu-vin li a{
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Pode ser um problema com hierarquia de classes já que está usando o WP, Temta colocar `font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif !important;` que deve resolver

Comment: também não deu!

Comment: Tenta chamar essa fonte em um arquivo separado. Cria um HTML novo do zero e importa a Font-family para ver se vai, isso já elimina algumas possibilidades

Comment: no editor do stackoverflow ele ja não funcionou

Comment: Só consegui fazer importanto direto do link `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet"> ` usando **@import** também não funcionou aqui...

Comment: já tentei assim também não funcionou!